# Is there something can stretch to fill all remaining space when using ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I made a simple custom control to contain some parameter, and put all of these controls in a ItemsControl like this.
[image]
[image]
I have tried all my mind to stretch the items for filling all remaining space, but VerticalContentAlignment do not work right , containing the items in a UniformGrid either.

There's nothing but a simple control for displaying, but i got many of them in my project, i don't want to use to many RowDefinition
Is there a simple way to do the stretch thing?

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  Title  -->
    <Grid Height="56">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            Margin="20,15"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="{StaticResource FontForTitle}"
            Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Column="2"
            Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
            Margin="7"
            Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
            Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility, Converter={local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    </Grid>

    <!--  Status Bars  -->
    <Border
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="{Binding StatusBarsHeight}"
        Background="{Binding Status,Converter={local:LightGrayToGreenByBooleanConverter}}"
        />

    <!--  Parameter  -->
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:DisplayLabel />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You may use a UniformGrid as the ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl.

Comment: I have tried, but i want to use my own control  in the ItemsControl. ItemsPanel seems do not allow a custom control containing in it

Comment: That is not true. You can use all WPF Panels as ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:DisplayLabel />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Exactly what i want! Thanks a lot!